# bean validation together with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey

Tomcat application, and I use Spring for dependency injection. I also use Jersey for rest calls, now I need to do some bean validation. I found examples that it is easy to to if I were using Spring MVC @RequestMapping for rest calls. But using Jersey and hibernate validator together things got ugly.

```
@POST
@Path("/addSomething")
public void addSomething(Something something) {

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Something>> violations = validator.validate(something);
    if(violations.size()>0){
        throw new BadRequestException("illegal input");
    }

   ..
}
```

This works, but I need to repeat this for every post request. Which is ugly.

Is there a way to neatly handle bean validation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about use also contrainst groups XD.

```
public void validateEntity(final Object object, final Class<? extends Default>... classes)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> errors = validator.validate(object, classes);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(returnErrors(errors));
    }
}


public String returnErrors(final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> errors) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (final ConstraintViolation<Object> error : errors) {
        builder.append(error.getMessage());
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: why do we need final Class<? extends Default>... classes?

Comment: If you want to pass a list of group Constraints, all of them extends from javax.validation.groups.Default, just in case you want to add groups, it is very helpful mechanism to define which constraints applies in which scenario

Answer (score 1):

You could improve it a bit by having a generic validate method that takes an Object as parameter, e.g.:

```
public static void validateBean(Object object) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(object);
    if(violations.size()>0){
        throw new BadRequestException("illegal input");
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call `validateBean(someObject);` at the beginning of each post method.